# Сломалась разработка любых проектов C++ в VS studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

После установки WDK у меня сломалась разработка любых проэктов на C++.
Для такого простого кода, как "Привет Мир" выводит 436 ошибок.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Большинство ошибок по типу: E1696 Не удалось найти источник файла, E2082 Глобальная область не содержит, требует точки с запятой, идентификатор не определен, шаблон класса не содержит член. И последняя C1083 Не удалось найти файл включения.

Уже смотрел и искал разное. Полностью удалил WDK, несколько раз удалил и переустановил студию. Ошибки все так же остаются и ни один проект на C++ не работает. Даже не знаю, что делать.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Это пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230514/after-installing-wdk-vc-is-broken

Comment: @КоржикБогатырский Не помогло, теперь 435 ошибок.

Comment: Проблема решилась полным удалением студии, всех ее компонентов, связанных папок и записей в реестре.